# How to pass the angular's directive's link and controller to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say that I have a straight forward directive:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('myDiv', ['MyService1', 'MyService2', 
        function(MyService1, MyService2) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.myVars = MyService1.generateSomeList();

                    MyService2.runSomeCommands();

                    // Do a lot more codes here
                    // Lines and Lines

                    // Now run some embedded function here
                    someEmbeddedFunction();

                    function someEmbeddedFunction()
                    {
                        // More embedding
                        // This code is really getting nasty
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

The code above has so much indentation and crowded that at least to me, it is very hard to read and unenjoyable to work with.

Instead, I want to move the `link` and `someEmbeddedFunction` out and just call them. So something along the lines of this:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, MyService1, MyService2)
{
    scope.myVars = MyService1.generateSomeList();

    MyService2.runSomeCommands();

    // Do a lot more codes here
    // Lines and Lines

    // Now run some embedded function here
    someEmbeddedFunction();
}

function someEmbeddedFunction()
{
    // This is much nicer and less tabbing involved
}

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('myDiv', ['MyService1', 'MyService2', 
        function(MyService1, MyService2) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: link          // This is line that I need to get it to work
            }
    ]);
```

The problem is that `MyService1` and `MyService2` are not passed to the link function (i.e. if I only had a link function with `scope, element, attrs` then the code above would work just fine). How can I pass those variables as well?

I tried to call the function as `link: link(scope, element, attrs, MyService1, MyService2)` but then it says `scope, element, attrs` are undefined.

**Note** I realize that the `someEmbeddedFunction` can right now be moved out without a problem. This was just for demonstrating purposes.

**Edit**

The only way I can think to get this to work is call the `link` function from the directive this way:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
    link(scope, element, attrs, MyService1, MyService2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, the only way to call your non-standard link function is to do so manually within a "standard" link function.

i.e.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
    link(scope, element, attrs, MyService1, MyService2);
}
```

This is because the link function doesn't get injected like other functions in Angular. Instead, it always gets the same series of arguments (regardless of what you call the function parameters):

1. The scope
2. The element (as an `angular.element()` instance)
3. The `attrs` object
4. An array or single controller instance that you `require`d
5. A transclude function (if your directive uses transclusion)

Nothing else.

Comment: Alright fair enough. Now is my way of doing this considered bad in any way? I just would like to get rid of all the indentation and closure within closure.

Comment: Bonus tip: if you already use Lodash, you could do `link: _.partialRight(link, MyService1, MyService2)`, which is the same as what you had but in one line.

Comment: I would place all this code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) so that it doesn't clutter the global scope, but other than that, it's probably even a good idea, as you will be less likely to have memory leaks since it will be clearer where you are using variables than if you just use them from a closure.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Yes, each directive would be inside an IIFE. Okay thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I use this scheme to keep it simple & readable:

```
var awesomeDir = function (MyService, MyAnotherService) {

    var someEmbeddedFunction = function () {
        MyService.doStuff();
    };

    var link = function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
        someEmbeddedFunction();
    };

    return {
        template: '<div>...</div>',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link
    };

};

awesomeDir.$inject = ['MyService', 'MyAnotherService'];

app.directive('awesomeDir', awesomeDir);
```

Comment: What is the advantage of doing this vs what I did? This is adding an extra indentation than is necessary (i.e. just add all the injection and directive's objects directly on `app.directive(...)` and straight from indentation zero for the link function. Specially if i use IIFE, then it the link function would not be global and fine to use in multiple contexts accros files.

Comment: @Kousha They're pretty similar to me. When it is a question of style, there is not really a "right" or "wrong" way to do it. If you hate indentation, then that's your thing, but a lot of Angular developers don't. This is another perfectly valid way of laying out directive code, with the caveat that the code in this answer should be in an IIFE as you mentioned.